# Setting min/max for contourf and the legend

Tags: python, contour, contourf

I am trying to set the min/max values of a contour but for some reason, this code only modifies the color but not the legend itself. What might I be doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [0,0.05,0.1]
y = [2,1.75,1.5,1.25,1,0.75,0.5,0.25]

z = [[28.2, 34.4, 27. ],
   [27.3, 32.3, 32. ],
   [27.9, 30.3, 27.8],
   [36.3, 27.3, 28.2],
   [31. , 32.9, 30.6],
   [33.4, 30.7, 28. ],
   [30.9, 32.1, 28.7],
   [29.9, 26.5, 25.1]]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
plt.figure()                           
plt.contourf(X, Y, z, 100, cmap='viridis')
plt.clim(0,30)
plt.xticks(x) 
plt.yticks(y) 
plt.colorbar();

ax = plt.gca() #you first need to get the axis handle
ax.set_aspect(1/8) #sets the height to width ratio
```

This results in the following image where the contour color range has the right limits but the legend is still using the range from the z-array

[image]

Comment: Maybe try using `vmin, vmax` in your call to `contourf`. Or else the issue may be that you need to call `plt.colorbar` before doing `clim`

Comment: I tried both and neither solves the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to accomplish what I wanted to do

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, z, levels = np.linspace(0,30,10), cmap='viridis')
```

I only wish that it would assign the max value color to the value in z which exceeds the upper limit (30 in this case) instead of just leaving that area in the contour blank as seen below

[image]